# Flask-Socketio app getting timeout error on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask-socketio

Apologies, I am very new to web development and am trying to setup a flask-socketio application on Heroku by using gunicorn with gevent-websocket for WebSocket support. However, the app doesn't work. I've setup a simple example to try to illustrate the problem better.

Here is my application.py (doesn't use sockets here, but does in the real version)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.environ.get('SECRET')
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

app.run()
```

Here is my index.html (does nothing currently)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    test page
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the requirements.txt file

```
bidict==0.21.4
click==8.0.3
Flask==2.0.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.1.1
gevent==21.8.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
importlib-metadata==4.8.2
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.3
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
python-engineio==4.3.0
python-socketio==5.5.0
typing_extensions==4.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.2
zipp==3.6.0
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

And I'm running the app with this command in my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 application:app
```

The app doesn't work and the page for it says to check the logs. When I check the logs I see this error:
`at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=test-flasksocket.herokuapp.com request_id=c0acb584-c18e-4c86-ba4c-3d176de5b3ed fwd="174.134.134.150" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https`

Also, in the logs this text repeats indefinitely:

```
[2021-11-28 04:36:17 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:17)
[2021-11-28 04:36:17 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17)
[2021-11-28 04:36:17 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
* Serving Flask app 'application' (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: off
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I thought gunicorn was a production server, but it appears to be a development server?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The run method needs to be invoked like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I have no idea why running app.run() outside of this block would cause the problems I encountered but it seems to.